# I want to use variable in django template ,how can i use it .//

Tags: django, django-templates

```
<a href="{% static {{i.pdf}} %}"> 
</a>
```

> i want to use like this ( variable in template tag )but cant please
>   help thank you

Answer (score 2):

Without curly brackets:

```
<a href="{% static i.pdf %}">
```

If this is however a `FileField` or `ImageField`, you normally do this with the `.url` attribute:

```
<a href="{{ i.pdf.url }}">
```

Comment: Oh thanks @Willem Van Onsem, This is a very  silly mistake. I wasted my whole day on it.